# How DSE Spread Data?

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.0

We using DSE with Cassandra + Solr.

I'm not sure how it's spreading the data, let's say we have 6 nodes, replication factor of 3.

Our platform uses all the 6 nodes to query data, I query one node from the 6 there is a chance data will be missing?

Or I need to have the same replication factor as the number of the nodes I have if I want to use all the nodes from the platform.

How it's working?

Comment: Data Distribution in Cassandra is on base of RF, But Solr Data spreads across nodes on base of Shards. So mostly Shards are spread across all nodes, Only reason is Fast retrieval of Solr Indexed Data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Cassandra each node stores some parts of the data. When you build the cluster each node will be responsible for specific part of the data. That is decided based on the token value that is assigned to that node. Now when you insert or select the data, each insert or select will have a partition key. Based on that partition key a hash value is calculated and the data will be sent to node which is responsible for that specific token value.

If there are 6 nodes and RF =3 then within cluster you have 3 copies of entire data. The primary copy is stored based on the above concept. The replicas will be stored based on the replication class that you specify while you create keyspace. If you take `SimpleStrategy` it stores replica on next node in clockwise i.e replica of node1 will be stored on node2 and node3 and replica of node2 will be stored on node3 and node4 and so on.

If you query from one node then based on the partition key the query will be sent to specific node which is responsible for that partition keys. To know to which node your query will be sent you can use nodetool utility.

```
nodetool getendpoints <keyspace> <table> <key>
```

This will give you the node Ip where the query will be sent to get the result

Answer (score 0):

If you have 6 nodes and RF 3 it means 3 copies of data exist in your cassandra cluster. Data availability also depends on consistency level. if you are using ONE consistency and 2 node down then also will get data and no loss but if TWO, QOURAM, THREE or ALL consistency then scenario will be different.

Comment: But how I will know where the data exists? From which node to get the data that the Cassandra spread it.

Comment: For this, You can query with TRACING ON and will get the trace log.

Comment: So I need to know in advance where is my data?

Comment: Data is distributing based on hash in cassandra so when you are inserting the data just enable the trace check the trace logs.

Comment: Its masterless, send it to any node and it will go where it needs to be. If you really want driver to send it to the right replica just use the token aware load balancing policies in driver and it will do it automatically for you.